# Reading and writing a file in byte array in C/C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a file in C/C++ and store it in a byte array, once the data is stored I am trying to write it back again. But when I write it back I am not able save it properly, I loose some bytes some where

Eg: If I try to save a file of `2161 KB` then the new file create is saved with size of `2160 KB`, means I am loosing some data some where in this process but I am not able to find it ??

```
//Getting the file name
cout<<"Enter Filename\n";
char filePath[100];
cin >> filePath;
FILE *file = NULL;
if ((file = fopen(filePath, "rb")) == NULL)
    cout << "File Failed To Load\n";
else
    cout << "File Loaded Successfully\n";

//Getting the size
long prev=ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
long fileSize =ftell(file);
fseek(file,prev,SEEK_SET);

//Creating a buffer and saving it back
BYTE *fileBuf = new BYTE[fileSize];
cout << "fileSize" << fileSize;
fread(fileBuf, fileSize, 1, file);
FILE* file2 = fopen( "test_output.dat", "wb" );
fwrite( fileBuf, 1, fileSize, file2 );
cout<<"\nsaved";
```

What I am trying to read a file and store it in a `new BYTE[fileSize]` array and write the file back from the array

Any suggestions ?

**EDIT**

This is the output for the size check

```
Enter Filename
test.rar
File opened successfully
fileSize 2212314
savedFile opened successfully
fileSize 2211840
```

This is filesize when i read it `2212314` and after writing when I read it again i get `2211840`

Comment: On which operating system? `ftell`, `fseek`, `fread` and `fwrite` all return a value and could fail (see `errno`). Also, C & C++ are different languages. Choose one!

Comment: Using visual studio 2010 in windows 7 32 bit. but how do i get the size then ??

Comment: what is the difference? a newline or \0 at the end? and also, which part is OOP (as suggested with the tag)

Comment: I am not sure,but try using `fread` and `fwrite` in same way. In `fread` you read `1` block of size `fileSize`, in `fwrite` you write `fileSize` blocks of size `1`.

Comment: This isn't C. It uses `cout`

Comment: @Roddy It is C, just using cout.

Comment: You output the filesize to the screen. Is that the filesize the same as your input or your output file? Also, check if you don't run this program while the input is still written to.

Comment: @Roddy: The question specifies C/C++

Comment: @Wimmel : The file sizes differe

Comment: @MadHatter : Can you answer via code pls

Comment: @x29a : OOP was added to gather attention, Please avoid writing less useful comments

Comment: Could you simply compare files' contents using some hex editor? This way you'd be sure files are different/equal.

Comment: @GirishNair take one example; what is the size of the inputfile, what is the size you write on the screen, what is the size of the output file.

Comment: @SChepurin: seems that my final option

Comment: @GirishNair than add the code too where you read the file the second time. And what is the real size of test.rar on disk, and what is the real size of test_output.dat on disk (when you check using file properties)?

Comment: @GirishNair Yes, but you're not programming in C. you're programming in C++.

Comment: @GirishNair The output can NOT have come from that program. Please show the *real* code and the *real* output.

Comment: @GirishNair, when you re-read the file, you didn't forget to use "rb" with `fopen`, did you?

Comment: @GirishNair - One other thing: Adding irrelevant or incorrect tags to "attract attention" is self-defeating. The way to attract attention is with a well written question with an SCCCE showing the problem. http://sccce.org

Comment: @GirishNair : Try using `fwrite( fileBuf, fileSize, 1, file2 );`

Comment: @Roddy : Here is the dropbox link for the project https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7j6t0pygblr1vh6/hIxUmH9ezp. I have solved it any way check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're checking the actual size. Windows has different ways of showing it.

Compare the "Size" in bytes (e.g.16666) rather than the "size on disk", which will be rounded up depending on the filesystem.

[image]

---

### Update

Your drop box link has this code like this:-

```
FILE* output = fopen( "test_output.dat", "wb" );
fwrite( fileBuf, 1, fileSize, output );
std::cout<<"\nsaved";

FILE *file2 = NULL;
if ((file2 = fopen( "test_output.dat", "rb")) == NULL)
    std::cout << "Could not open specified file\n";
else
    std::cout << "File opened successfully\n";

long prev2=ftell(file2);
fseek(file2, 0L, SEEK_END);
long fileSize2 =ftell(file2);
fseek(file2,prev2,SEEK_SET);

std::cout << "fileSize" << fileSize2;
```

Here's the problem : You don't `fclose` the file after writing to it. So when your second `fopen` tries to determine the file size, there's still buffered data waiting to be written.  Just add `fclose(output);` after the `fwrite`. If you don't do this, the buffered data will only be written at the point when your program exits.

(This is a classic case where the problem was almost impossible to see until you provided a [SCCCE](http://sscce.org/) - which means the 50+ lines of filereader.cpp, not a massive dropbox file...)

Comment: Nope the file that I read and then What i write are having different sizes,Its not with respect to disk size or something like that. I dont know the reason why its different :(